# Meaning of the then king

Tags: adverbs

Meaning of **the then king** according to my book is

> The king **then reigning**

Can I say

> The king **reigning then**

Is there any difference. Is there any rule governing the position of **then**

Answer (score 2):

The use of “then” here is an adjective, and sounds better before the verb. They’re both pretty much the same as far as meaning goes.

Also, other ways you can say this:

- “The king reigning during that time”
- “The king reigning at that time”

Answer (score -1):

> The ***then*** king

It is a Noun Phrase (NP) with the head noun being *king*, The preposition *then* along with the head form a *Nominal*.

The structure of the NP is like this:

> DETERMINER <sub>(realized by a DETERMINATIVE)</sub> + [Pre-Head MODIFIER <sub>(realized by a PREPOSITION)</sub> + HEAD <sub>(realized by a NOUN)</sub>]

The part inside the [...] is called *Nominal*.

Both *the king then reigning...* and *the king reigning then...* are correct. But they are not complete sentence.